# SP Init SSO using javasaml

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml, federated-identity

I am quite new to this world and learned a lot in last two weeks.Coming to the point, I am drafting a solution for Service Provider Initiated SSO(on the application) supporting multiple Idp's. I am using onelogin's javasaml library and configured the sample kit to use our own identity provider to generate authentication request/response to understand the protocol.

Following are the questions I need help to understand further. Plesae advise.

## **Identify Customer Idp**

1. As I mentioned, Our application will initiate the sso flow and
   should support multiple Idp's. I am looking to have one common
   protected resource for the customers to initiate this flow.Am i
   wrong to think like that? like using query string to differenciate and   identify IDP.
   https://www.myapp.com?param=customerid
2. I also learnt that application URLs can contain subdomain
   information that is mapped to a unique customer to identify the
   Idp.How do I implement this?
3. is there any other approaches? without asking the users to select an identifier.

## **User**

In my solution, app username may be different from the sso username. I learnt that I can request the Idp providers to provide my application username as attribute in the saml response through the customer user store.

5. May customer send sp application username as querystring(like in question 1)?
6. Is there any other approach to get the sp application username? again without asking the users to identify.

Thank you for sharing your knowledge and guidence.

Answer (score 1):

If plain SAML based WebSSO is performed (no account linking) then authentication (an so user identification) only happens on the IdP side, not the SP side. The SP 'just' consumes the assertion about the authenticated identity. The assertion can included attribute statements which the SP (application) can use to map identities to local 'user profiles'. The standard SAML meta data does not offer a way to define which attribute statements should be sent, so you need to negotiate this with the admins of the IdP.

IdP discovery can be done in different ways, SAML spec talks about the preferred IdP cookie.

You can either present a list of IdPs the user can choose from or use some information from the HTTP request to do some smart guessing.

Comment: Ty Bernard. What do you mean plain SAML based WebSSO? is there any other approach here? I am yet to talk to the Idp's admin. So I would really appreciate more knowledge on this.

Comment: SAML would also allow for so called account linking (which is also some times called federation).  In that case you have 2 identity silos, one on the IdP side and one on the SP side and the accounts should be linked together. To achieve this the 'persistent' NameIdFormat is used which could be a hint for the SP to provide an authentication dialog. If authenticated, an account link is established at both entities and only an opaque handle is exchanged in the future. When the SP receives this opaque handle in future assertions from the IdP it knows which identity this is linked to.